# sufficient statistic for n-point distribution that depends of one parameter

Tags: self-study, multinomial-distribution, sufficient-statistics, point-estimation

I'm studiying the concept of sufficient statistic, but I have a question that I can't resolve... I hope someone can help me.

My question is the next:

I suppose that I do n independent trials with m possible outcomes (1,2,...,m), let the probability of the ith outcome be $p_i$ in each trial. But each probability depends of an unknown real parameter $\theta$, i.e. $p_i(\theta)$. 
If $X_i$ denotes the number of trials resulting in outcome i then

$P(X_1 =x_1,...,X_m = x_m) \propto p_1(\theta)^{x_1}p_2(\theta)^{x_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot p_m(\theta)^{x_m}$.

Then, what is the suficient statistic for $\theta$?

I think that I understand the multinomial case when the probabilities are not functions of $\theta$, but in this case I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you recognize this as exponential family? Does that suggest anything to you?

Comment: yes... If $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=n$, then $p_1(θ)^{x_1}⋅⋅⋅p_m(θ)^{x_m}=exp(nln(p_1(θ))+\sum_{i=2}^n x_i log(p_i(θ)/p_1(θ)))$. Thus my pdf belongs to exponential family. In this case, Is $T(x)=x_i$ a sufficient statistic for θ? or Is the vector $T= (x_1,...,x_n)$?

Comment: Reposting the comment doesn't change anything; my lack of response was deliberate. I was hoping you'd take the intervening time to reconsider whether your suggestion made any sense.  Consider an elementary special case like a plain and simple trinomial for example (take some specific one) and work it through. The fact that you reposted the comment verbatim suggests you thought about it not at all in the interim. Please reconsider your suggestions now.

Comment: This question begs for the `self-study` tag!